# Ruby error with tmail gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I was having problems running this script ,please see https://github.com/thekindofme/gmail_attachment_downloader/blob/master/gmail_attachment_downloader.rb

It runs fine on my machine but when i upload it and run bluehost's server it gives me an error, although i already installed the required gem

```
/usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- tmail (LoadError)
       from /usr/lib64/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
       from mail.rb:12
```

What could be the possible error?

Thanks in advance

Ryan

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include rubygems in your script:

```
require 'rubygems'
```